# Add other class content with reference class value

Tags: php, css, javascript, jquery, html

[image]

Hello, in my Wordpress project I have reference values that I have enclosed in yellow and red lines using custom fields (can vary; orange, purple, etc.).

I want to print the same values in the other green fields I marked.

When I come to the black section, it will automatically change to black, and when I come to the white section, it will automatically change to white.

can i solve it with js.

Thank you everyone

Comment: How are the original values output? It’s impossible to say what to do without knowing that.

Comment: I manually print with myself (custom fields)

Comment: I don’t understand the question then. What are you trying to do?